# Getting extra data while calling data using BETWEEN for date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with a table like:-

```
ID  Name Amount Date

001 abc 200 01/05/2014

001 abc 200 02/05/2014

001 abc 200 03/05/2014
.
.
.
001 abc 200 31/05/2014

001 abc 200 01/06/2014

001 abc 200 02/06/2014
```

When following query is executed:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE Date_ between '01/05/2014' AND '31/05/2014'
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) DESC";
```

it is showing an extra data considering the dates 01/06/2014 and 02/06/2014, along with data of date between 01/05/2014 and 31/05/2014

How to resolve it?

Comment: My Date column is in varchar

Comment: your between will not work, you will need to use `CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) >= CONVERT(DateTime, '01/05/2014', 103) and CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '31/05/2014', 103)` in your where condition. Range condition will not serve your purpose of filtering the records between dates.

Comment: Txs Murtaza it worked.......txs once again

Comment: I have added the answer to your question - please mark it as answer if it has helped you to solve your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your between will not work, you will need to use -

WHERE CONDITION AS

`CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) >= CONVERT(DateTime, '01/05/2014', 103) and CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '31/05/2014', 103)`

in your where condition. Range condition will not serve your purpose of filtering the records between dates.