# Comparing dates in SQL returns wrong records

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to locate a date in database between two specific dates entered by user. Something like:

SELECT date FROM table WHERE date>=dateFrom AND date<=dateTO

I have the following table:

[image]

I have made a mistake saving the date as VARCHAR and now i have to do all the str_to_date and date_format as i am using phpMyAdmin. I somehow did it but i am facing this strange problem using this query:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date(data,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM montaggio WHERE data>=date_format(str_to_date('29/08/2014','%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')
```

The query would return to me only the date `19/08/2014` where as i expected it to return `01/09/2014`. On the other hand if it enter the query

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date(data,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM montaggio WHERE data>=date_format(str_to_date('29/08/2014','%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') AND data<=date_format(str_to_date('05/09/2014','%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')
```

The query returns nothing.

I am using phpMyAdmin.
What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting extra data while calling data using BETWEEN for date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678714/getting-extra-data-while-calling-data-using-between-for-date)

Comment: PLease see my answer here if you want solution for SQL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678714/getting-extra-data-while-calling-data-using-between-for-date/25679235#25679235

Comment: This is why we **store dates as dates**. You really need to amend your table definition and then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do seem a bit confused.  All the operations on dates should be done on the *date* data type.  There is no need to convert things back to strings:

```
SELECT data
FROM montaggio
WHERE str_to_date(data, '%d/%m/%Y') >= str_to_date('29/08/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

You seem to understand the real solution, which is to store dates/times in the database using the correct type.  If you have to use strings for dates, then always stored them as YYYY-MM-DD, so comparisons and sorting will work correctly.

Comment: i am on my way to make those changes, i just wanted to see how i do with strings. Learning phase... :) Thank you for the suggestion though.